# Control Structures: Change the following code (...) to generate "else"

Tags: if-statement, syntax, controls, truetype, invalid-argument

How can I change the following code to include an `else` statement?

```py
if 2 + ... == 4 ...
  if 3 * ... == 9 ...
    print ("if")
  else: 
    print ("else")
```

This is what I have tried:

```py
if 2 + 2 == 4 / 2
  if 3 * 3 == 9 / 3
    print ("if")
  else: 
    print ("else")
```

However, I am getting a syntax error:

> File "", line 1
> if 2 + 2 == 4 / 2
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Did this as well same same: if 2 + 2 == 4 
  if 3 * 3 == 9 
    print ("if")
  else: 
    print ("else")

Comment: You forgot the colon `:` at the end of the `if` line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, it is useful to provide you a finished solution for your study task.

The if-statement line hast to end with a `:` (as the `else` does)

But perhaps you also have a look at your maths think about the `else`, to which 'if` it belongs to.

---

**Edit**:
By your answers I've got the impression, you're not watching for the correct intents.

The program skeleton is:

```py
if 2 + ... == 4 ...
  if 3 * ... == 9 ...
    print ("if")
  else: 
    print ("else")
```

But your answer seems to have changed the skeleton code this way:

```py
if 2 + ... == 4 ...
  if 3 * ... == 9 ...
    print ("if")
else: 
    print ("else")
```

Please note the *missing intent* of the `else` in the second version!
This little change changes the logic of the program and will prohibit a successful solution.

Comment: I tried this and that worked: if 2 + 2 == 4 / 2:
  if 3 * 3 == 9 / 3:
    print ("if")
else: 
    print ("else")

Comment: This only worked, if you killed the intents of the `else`. But that's tricked around and not the task ! — As written in your question the `else:` has an intent. — Which if as to ben TRUE? Which if has to be FALSE?

Comment: The I turn the first if into FALSE 2+3 ==4, while I keep the second one TRUE 3*3==9, it goes to the else code! When i keep the first if TRUE 2+2==4 the it goes to the if code if. My solution know is: 2 + 3 == 4:
  if 3 * 3 == 9:
    print ("if")
else: 
    print ("else")

Comment: In these one-liner-syntax of the comments kill the essentials of the python language (the intents of a line are eaten). — Your "solution now" says: first `if` = FALSE, second `if`= TRUE. — If you insert that in the original code of the task (the `else` has the same intent as the second `if`), then you get *nothing!* — You won't get your points, if you change the logic of the task's skeleton code.